# Inversion of Laurent series

Tags: cv.complex-variables

For a power series $f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i z^i$ with $a_1$ nonzero, [Lagrange's inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) gives an explicit way to compute the Taylor coefficients of the inverse function.

Is there any analogous formula for Laurent series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lagrange inversion formula is meant to give you the Taylor series expansion of $f^{-1}$ at the point $f(0)$.  If $f$ has a Laurent series instead, then it means that $f(0) = \infty$ and that $f$ is meromorphic.  The Taylor series at $\infty$ of $f^{-1}$ then doesn't particularly mean anything unless you change to a different coordinate patch on the Riemann sphere, for instance $\zeta = 1/z$.  So you can first switch to the function $1/f$, which has a usual Taylor series, and then use the standard Lagrange inversion formula for $(1/f)^{-1}$.

(If I have understood the question correctly.  Maybe this answer is too straightforward to address the real question.)

Comment: Actually, that's just what I needed. Thanks. I'm embarrassed that I wasn't able to figure out such a straightforward thing on my own!